# Convert image from one format to another sent to STDOUT

Tags: imagemagick

I'd like to convert an image from `.jpg` to `.png`. This works just fine:

```
convert input.jpg output.png
```

But, I'm trying to have my output go to STDOUT instead of a file, which the manual says to use `"-"`.

I tried using:

```
convert input.jpg -.png
```

But it just creates a file called `-.png`.

Is it possible to convert an image from one format to another and have it go to STDOUT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use a command like this to convert a JPEG to a PNG on `stdout`:

```
magick input.jpg PNG:-
```

These specifiers work on input as well as output. So, if you have a TIFF on `stdin` and want a 32-bit RGBA PNG on stdout:

```
magick TIFF:- PNG32:-
```

---

You often need these specifiers to ensure a specific filetype when it is not explicitly given, or you want to use a different extension. So, say you have some CCD device that produces RGB data in a raw binary file called `image.bin` and you want **ImageMagick** to read it. You can tell **ImageMagick** the format *without* having to change the filename (to `image.rgb`) like this:

```
magick -size WxH RGB:image.bin result.png
```

The possible formats are documented [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).

---

The king of all of these formats is `MIFF` which is guaranteed to be able to hold any and all things you might throw at it, including floating-point values, transparency, masks, concatenated streams... so if you need a format to pass between **ImageMagick** commands, `MIFF` is a good option. An example, just to demonstrate because it is not optimal, might to be to concatenate two images from 2 separate **ImageMagick** commands into a third command that makes an animated GIF:

```
{ magick -size 100x60  xc:red miff:- ; magick -size 100x60 xc:blue miff:- ; } | magick -delay 80 miff:- result.gif
```

[image]